# How to switch between two pointers in a struct

Tags: rust

Here is a snippet of Rust pseudocode defining a struct:

```
struct A {
    a : *B;
    b : *B;
    pub c : *B;
}
```

(The pointers are C pointers, not sure if they should be `Box` or something else yet.) Here `c` will always be set to `a` or `b`, and all access will be through `c`; auxiliary methods defined for `A` will set `c = a` or `c = b`.

What is the Rust-y way to do this? My first attempt used `a,b: RefCell<Box<B>>` and `c:Box<B>`, with `c` always `borrow`ed out to one or the other. But then I hit a snag in defining `new`:

```
new(b1: B, b2: B) -> A {
    let acell = RefCell::new(Box::new(b1)),
    A { a: acell,
        b: RefCell::new(Box::new(b2)),
        c: *acell.borrow() }
}
```

This doesn't work because `acell` "does not live long enough" (dies at the end of `new()` instead of escaping with the return).

Comment: Isn't `c` supposed to be a copy of `a` or `b`?

Comment: @MatthieuM. It can't literally be a copy because this is Rust and that would be unsafe (if I understand correctly). Instead, access to the copies `a` and `b` are "protected" through a `RefCell` with the promise that they won't be accessed except when switching `c`. If you were to attempt to access `a` directly, that (should) cause a panic.

Comment: Actually, it can be literally a copy, if using raw pointers. Of course, this will require unsafe code, but cross-attributes borrow are just not a thing in Rust.

Comment: @MatthieuM. True, of course. I'm just hoping there is a way to do this without explicitly using unsafe code, since it seems to be safe at first glance (and your answer indeed shows that it is operationally equivalent to a safe solution).

Comment: I do not know any solution that do not use `unsafe`.

Comment: @MatthieuM. The idea behind using `RefCell` here is that there is probably no way to check it at compile time so I want to just punt the issue and rely on runtime checking, which I know I can satisfy. Only, I'm probably not using it right and I am still getting compile errors.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution:

```
struct A {
    a: B,
    b: B,
    c: u32,
}

impl A {
    pub fn new(a: B, b: B) -> A { A { a: a, b: b, c: 0 } }

    pub fn switch(&mut self) { self.c += 1; self.c %= 2; }

    pub fn get(&self) -> &B {
        match self.c {
            0 => self.a,
            1 => self.b,
            _ => unreachable!(),
        }
    }
}
```

We simply side-step the issue by NOT having multiple references to the same object; this allows us to be safe. There is a small sacrifice to syntax, but otherwise it should be unnoticeable performance-wise.

---

An `unsafe` solution:

```
struct A {
    a: *mut B,
    b: *mut B,
    c: *mut B,
    _marker: PhantomData<B>,
}

impl A {
    pub fn new(a: B, b: B) -> A {
        A {
            a: Box::new(a).into_raw(),
            b: Box::new(b).into_raw(),
            c: a,
            _marker: PhantomData,
        }
    }

    pub fn switch(&mut self) {
        self.c =
            if self.a == self.c { self.b } else { self.a }
    }

    pub fn get(&self) -> &B { unsafe { *self.c } }

    pub fn get_mut(&mut self) -> &mut B { unsafe { *self.c  } }
}

impl Drop for A {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            Box::from_raw(self.a);
            Box::from_raw(self.b);
        }
    }
}
```

I would not make `c` public though, given it's unsafe to use.

Comment: This is not an option in my use case. I have simplified the MCVE so that it seems as though this is reasonable, but I really am looking for something that compiles down to the equivalent of C `B* a; B* b; B* c;` with `c=a` and `c=b` methods.

Comment: To be more specific, the real problem has `c` switching between `a` and `f(a,b)`, where `f` consumes its arguments and doesn't give them back (so I have to store `a` on the side so I can switch back).

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: I have created a solution with the exact structure layout you requested; it's `unsafe`, obviously. I can't do much more, because the C in MCVE stands for complete, and apparently you are not quite exposing all requirements :)

Comment: What is the `PhantomData` for? And why did you not opt for `a,b: Box<B>` directly?

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: I suggest you read the documentation for PhantomData; and I am not using `a: Box<B>` because I want to call out the unsafety. If a maintainer were to accidentally suppose that my using `a: Box<B>` meant that `a` is the only pointer to that instance of `B`, then it would mean trouble down the line.